# Windows 11 Pro Computer Won't Sleep

Tags: windows, audio, sleep

I know the culprit is my new Razer Blackshark V2 headphones since this issue only started after I got them. The headphones seems to interfere with GeForce experience. The only workaround I have found was disabling desktop capture in GeForce experience which lets my computer go to sleep. I am looking to see if there is another way around this since sometimes I would want to capture stuff on my screen on occasion.

Comment: `I know the culprit is my new Razer Blackshark V2 headphones since this issue only started after I got them.` ? Does that mean if a piano drops on you while going out for the first pizza in years that it was somehow related to the pizza?  I am not saying that you are incorrect.  I am saying that screws fall out all of the time.  The world is an imperfect place.  Also, those headphones should work just fine without razer crapware running.  Have you tried uninstalling it and see what happens?

Comment: Also.. junk that runs at startup can be run (or killed) at any time.  Have you tried managing GeForce startup garbage if and when you want it?  Why am I so negative?  Because vendors make lazy background bloatware that isn't needed for their products to function and don't give a hoot if it eating up your ram or cycles.  You might consider managing the apps they run yourself when you want the functionality and don't when you don't.

Comment: CMasMas I literally explained that when I turn off desktop capture it fixes it for me and I searched up about desktop capture not letting computer sleep and guess what people had the same problem as me but there was no solution. I have tested the headphones on 4 different computers and it is this specific headset that causes this I have had multiple headphones and only started with this about sleep issue.

Comment: Why I was implying background application is at it's core, most USB devices don't use anything custom and built-in drivers are almost never a cause of preventing  .  It is the add on user-mode (non driver) junk that might prevent sleep.  In this specific case, it is possible that the headset software is triggering something in the capture software which is triggering something in the razer software.. etc etc.. ACPI is a pain to troubleshoot.